# Changing a file directory when using socket.io and node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have created a successful connection and handled events of someone connecting and disconnecting. However I am now trying to clean up my folders to create something that is a bit more clean to work with.

I have looked at some examples of changing directories, however it seems that I am missing something.

I am quite new to using node and socket, so might seem a bit obvious with the problem.

My basic file structure is i have a main app folder, with an index.html file, server folder with all the relevant node and socket code, then a public folder with css, js, image folders.

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luFUj.png)

So my index is in the route.
I do also find when I try linking stylesheets and js files it returns a 404 error. Not entirely sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Sets a base path for acessing all files
app.use(express.static('/'));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + './index.html');
});
```

EDIT:

Updated file structure:
[New Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luFUj.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need the `app.get`, `express.static` handles indexes for you. You're also serving from `/` instead of `../public` (I'm guessing based on your structure). Try this:

```
app.use(express.static('../public));
```

If it were me, I'd move the index.html into the public folder, and move your server logic into the root. That way you can do

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: What would someone use a .get then for?

Comment: @factor_za `app.<verb> is for implementing server logic in javascript, like the example in the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method).

Comment: @factor_za I've edited my answer based on my best guess.

Comment: I have updated my file structure image. I have read the doc, cause basically i have made a very simple version of a chat system, just to practice. The tut that was suggested they used a .get, so its always confused me between a use and get

Also do you not feel that node_modules sitting in the root is bad practice? reason I was storing my stuff in a server folder was just to neaten things up. Just wanted to know your thoughts

Comment: @factor_za Assuming there's an `index.html` in the `public` folder, that should work fine. If you'd prefer to confine your logic to a subfolder there's no reason not to, just make sure you move `package.json` and `node_modules` in with it. Having your logic in the project root and assets in a subfolder is fairly standard practice, and larger applications will break up their logic into modules, sometimes spread among various subfolders.

Comment: Yea will have to figure out how I then implement logic to then link modules to my main app.js and all that. But otherwise I get what you are saying. Based off of whats now been done by this my css is linking correctly, so SASS is working well. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your index.html is a folder up from your server js file you need to change it to

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '../index.html');
```